# Browser history needs a DOM ( react-router 4 )

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-v4, server-side-rendering

I am trying to implement server-side-rendering in my react app. I can't access the DOM with server implementation of react, react-dom and react-router. I either have "Browser history needs a DOM" errors.

So my guess is there is something wrong in the way I am wrapping up my component on server or client side.

I will share my structure and important files which are involved in this exercise !

server.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server';
// import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router';
import {StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-
redux';
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import api from "../src/actions/api";
import rootReducer from "../src/reducers/index";
import routes from '../src/routes/routes';

const app = express();

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('*', (req,res)=>{

const axiosMiddlewareOptions = {
    interceptors: {
        request: [
            (action, config) => {
                if (sessionStorage.token) {
                    config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Token '+ sessionStorage.token;
                }

                return config
            }
        ]
    }
};
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const appRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const createStoreWithMiddleware = 
applyMiddleware(multiClientMiddleware(api, axiosMiddlewareOptions), 
appRouterMiddleware)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, {}, 
window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f);

const context = {};
const html = renderToString(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={context}>
            <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes}/>
        </StaticRouter>
    </Provider>
);

res.send(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title>Title</title>
            <base href="/"/>
            <link href="assets/img/favikin-hw.png" rel="shortcut 
 icon" type="image/x-icon" />
            <meta name="viewport" content=" width=device-width, 
 maximum-scale=1">
        </head>

        <body>
            <div class="wrapper">${html}</div>
        </body>

    </html>

`)
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, ()=>{
   console.log('Server is Listening')
});
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { ConnectedRouter, routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import { multiClientMiddleware } from 'redux-axios-middleware';
import api from "./actions/api";
import rootReducer from "./reducers/index";
import routes from './routes/routes';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import '../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import '../assets/style.css';
import '../node_modules/react-datetime/css/react-datetime.css';
import '../node_modules/react-select/dist/react-select.min.css';

const axiosMiddlewareOptions = {
    interceptors: {
    request: [
        (action, config) => {
            if (sessionStorage.token) {
                config.headers['Authorization'] = 'Token '+     sessionStorage.token;
            }

            return config
        }
    ]
    }
};
const history = createBrowserHistory();
const appRouterMiddleware = routerMiddleware(history);
const createStoreWithMiddleware =     applyMiddleware(multiClientMiddleware(api, axiosMiddlewareOptions),     appRouterMiddleware)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer, {},     window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f);

render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} children={routes}/>
    </Provider>,
document.querySelector('.wrapper'));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from "react";
import Header from '../components/Header/Header';
import Footer from '../components/Footer/Footer';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div className="wrapper-box">
                <div className="inner-wrapper">
                    <Header/>
                    {this.props.children}
                </div>
                <Footer/>
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
    }
}

App.propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

export default App;
```

routes.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App from '../containers/App';
import {
    Route,
    Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';
import MainPage from '../containers/MainPage/MainPage';
import DetailPage from '../components/DetailPage/DetailPage';
import AboutProject from '../containers/AboutProject/AboutProject';
import Contacts from '../containers/Contacts/Contacts';
import SectionPage from '../containers/SectionPage/SectionPage';
import SearchPage from '../containers/SearchPage/SearchPage';
import NoMatch from '../containers/NoMatch/NoMatch';


export default (
<App>
    <div>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={true} path='/' component={MainPage} />
            <Route path='/about_the_project' component={AboutProject} />
            <Route path='/contacts' component={Contacts} />
            <Route path="/search-results/:category/:term" component={SearchPage}/>
            <Route exact={true} path='/:name' component={SectionPage} />
            <Route path="/articles/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
            <Route path="/events/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
            <Route path="/news/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
            <Route path="/interviews/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
            <Route path="/technologies/:slug" component={DetailPage}/>
            <Route path='*' component={NoMatch}/>
        </Switch>
    </div>
    </App>
)
```

Comment: Do you really need to have the line `import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'` in your server code? I think that's the line where execution fails (presumably immediately after the server is run). Because if it doesn't, it should fail shortly after on the line `window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f)`. I'm afraid neither of those is going to work in Node environment. You need to find another way to manage user session on the server, if ever necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Error was resolved by using createMemoryHistory()

const history = createMemoryHistory();

Answer (score 0):

I don't have time yet to test it, but the ConnectRouter has a prop called isSSR that prevents subscribing to a DOM-only thing. (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/modules/ConnectedRouter.js)

My guess is you can now use a `memoryHistory` with it. (https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md)

Will try to get an example app up over the weekend.

Comment: Thanks it works. Maybe you can tell me what I need to do to get the date in the components for server rendering? By looking at the code of the page I can see only the header and footer that the server returned from App.js. But the code that is in the routes is not on the page, only preloader